# Формирование маркеров. Местоположение в реальном времени

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, json

У меня есть простое приложение на андроид, которое, например, каждую минуту отправляет координаты местоположения на сервер (простой php сайт). Там я их принимаю, и чисто ради интереса записываю в базу. Потом с базы беру последнюю запись формирую json строку передаю в js и отображаю координаты на карте.

Но что делать когда программу начинает использовать еще одно андроид устройство. Как одновременно отображать местоположение еще одного маркера? (тут моя выборка из базы последней записи как бы не подходит)

Думаю писать в базу также imei андроида.. для того чтобы если imei уже отображен на карте то обновлять координаты а если такого еще нет то создать новый маркер. 
Но вопрос как это с базы правильно выводить и формировать ассоциативный массив где ключем будет Imei андроида а значением уже все другие данный координаты и тд.

Подскажите начинающему как лучше

Comment: Вероятно, надо записывать в БД не только координаты, но и идентификатор устройства.

Comment: Далеко не на каждом устройстве можно достать imei. Тут либо самому пилить регистрацию устройств(генерировать на сервере id, отсылать устройству и сохранять в SharedPreferences), либо использовать ID от firebase например, если он подключен

Answer (score 0):

если в таблице есть поле id (PRIMARYKEY)

```
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM tablecoord WHERE imei='.$imei.' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
```